# cocos2dx getChildByTag function ,declaring the tag

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am trying to update score in an app using the method from this website

http://fabiosistemas.com.br/show-strings-using-numbers-in-cocos2d-x/

CCLabelBMFont *label2 = CCLabelBMFont::create( “Score: 0″, “Arial.fnt” );
addChild(label2, 100, kTagSprite2);

CCLabelBMFont* label2 = (CCLabelBMFont*) getChildByTag(kTagSprite2);
label2->setString(stringPontos);

compiler gives error: of the kTagSprite2 not declared in this scope
 how do i declare the KTagSprite2 , as in what type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `kTagSprite2` before using it, because it is not a keyword or any constant declared by cocos2d-x. So here you go..

We can assign an integer value as a tag to any `CCNode` in cocos2d.

```
//Global declaration
#define kTagSprite2 1234

//Here you are setting kTagSprite2 or 1234 as tag value of label2

addChild(label2, 100, kTagSprite2);

//Here you are getting the child to which kTagSprite2 or 1234 is assigned as tag value
//i.e your label. This will return a child which has 1234 as its tag value

CCLabelBMFont* label2 = (CCLabelBMFont*) getChildByTag(kTagSprite2);
label2->setString(stringPontos);
```

Hope this helps you.